# AWS EC2 with S3 PING Wildfly 8.2 session not shared

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, wildfly, mod-cluster

The two wildfly instances are not in the same session.

I have configured the following parts of the standalone-full-ha.xml :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
           <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" proxy-    list="10.0.0.146:6666" balancer="mycluster" advertise="false" connector="ajp">
</subsystem>
```

10.0.0.146 is the apache instance private IP.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:2.0" default-stack="tcp">
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="S3_PING">
                <property name="access_key">
                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                </property>
                <property name="secret_access_key">
                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                </property>
                <property name="location">
                    wildfly-bucket
                </property>
                <property name="timeout">
                    16000
                </property>
            </protocol>
            <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
            <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
            <protocol type="FD"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
            <protocol type="RSVP"/>
        </stack>
    </subsystem>
```

....

```
<interfaces>
   <interface name="management">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:10.0.0.210}"/>
   </interface>
  <interface name="public">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:10.0.0.210}"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="unsecure">
      <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
  </interface>
```

then I have started the instances (server1 and server2):

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.node.name=server1 -c standalone-full-ha.xml
```

In the server logging i get it right:

```
07:41:27,019 INFO [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService    Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [server2/web|1] (2)   [server2/web, server1/web]
```

Apache mod_cluster recognizes the two nodes.
In S3 I have granted all the permission to the “wildfly-bucket” to authenticated user, everyone and to myself.
I have also tried adding a bucket policy:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/laura"
           },
           "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wildfly-bucket/*"
         },
       {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/laura"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wildfly-bucket"
       }
   ]
```

}

The user “laura” is in a Group with AdministratorAccess.

I have set the two instances+apache in the same security group and even tried with the same availability zone.

For the security group I have set the following rules
INBOUND:

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 7600    0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080    0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
Custom ICMP Rule    Echo Reply  N/A 0.0.0.0/0
All ICMP    All N/A 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 9990    0.0.0.0/0
```

OUTBOUND:

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 7600    0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
```

What am I missing?

Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "not in the same session" ? I could help if you provide some output/log, e.g. with curl. For instance, you establish a JSESSIONID with ```server1``` and subsequent requests keep getting new JSESSIONID instead of keeping the established one?

Give it a shot with ```clusterbench-ee7-web/target/clusterbench.war``` from [clusterbench](https://github.com/Karm/clusterbench/tree/simplified-and-pure); ```mvn package -DskipTests``` as follows:

    ```curl http://BALANCER_IP:BALANCER_PORT/clusterbench/requestinfo -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt```